# How to retrieve unique records that have different IDs but the same name?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, group-by

Using Oracle 11g, I have the following results from the query:

```
select ID,NAME from table_a;

ID                NAME
----------------- ------------
1                 AA
2                 BB
3                 AA
4                 CC
5                 DD
6                 AA
```

What I am after, is a select query that will only return the unique names only from this list, together with ID. Out of any of the duplicate names in the above example, in this case, the three AA's, I only require one result of these duplicates, don't care which ID comes with it.

So actual result set I am after is as follows based on my requirement:

```
ID                NAME
----------------- ------------
1                 AA
2                 BB
4                 CC
5                 DD
```

As mentioned, out of the three AA's, it could've been ID 1 or 3 or 6 but only ever need one record for any duplicate names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [GROUP BY](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.6.1.0/ref/rrefsqlj32654.html) for this.

```
select MIN(ID), NAME from table_a GROUP BY NAME;
```

You have to set MIN(ID), otherwise oracle will not know which ID to choose

Comment: Your documentation link points to the JavaDB (= Apache Derby) database, not the Oracle database.

Answer (score 1):

```
select min(id) as id,
       name
from table_a
group by name;
```